# Remove n number of dot(.) from String in Java

Tags: java

I have the following string and I want to remove dynamic number of dot(.) at the end of the String.

```
"abc....."
```

**Dot(.) can be more than one**

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: You just remove . and used space

Comment: String s1="abc....";  
  String replaceString=s1.replaceAll("\\.","");  
  System.out.println(replaceString);

Comment: @Batty.. Why you ask me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.  It uses a regular expression to replace all dots at the end of your string with empty strings.

```
yourString.replaceAll("\\.+$", "");
```

Comment: Thanks you bro. Exactly what I want.

Comment: maybe need double backslash?

Comment: It needs to be `"\\.+$"`

Comment: Opps, you are correct

Comment: i tried my approach (see my answer) and it seems to work faster than regex. any ideas why? here goes the code https://pastebin.com/5Q6Uf13U

Comment: @ScaryWombat - Thanks, looks like it got lost when I copied and pasted from my IDE.  Fixed.

Comment: I'm curious as to why my answer was downvoted.

Comment: *I'm curious as to why my answer was downvoted* Strange things happen when you post code that does not even compile, let alone test

Answer (score 3):

Could do this to remove all `.`:

```
String a = "abc.....";
String new = a.replaceAll("[.]", "");
```

Remove just the trailing `.`'s:

```
String new = a.replaceAll("//.+$","");
```

Edit: Seeing the comment. To remove last `n` `.`'s

```
int dotsToRemove = 5; // whatever value n
String new = a.substring(0, s.length()-dotsToRemove);
```

Comment: I don't think they want to just remove all dots. They wanna receive some sort of user input indicating how many dots from the end to remove.

Comment: what should happen to string like "abc...cba....". His question is not clear.

Comment: That won't work - replaceAll() uses regular expressions, and '.' matches anything, so you end up with an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

how about using this function? seems to work faster than regex

```
public static String trimPoints(String txt)
    {
        char[] cs = txt.toCharArray();
        int index =0;
        for(int x =cs.length-1;x>=0;x--)
        {
            if(cs[x]=='.')
                continue;
            else
                {
                index = x+1;
                break;
                }
        }

        return txt.substring(0,index);
    }
```